# Java cannot find parent class

Tags: java, inheritance, drjava

I have this class, Person:

```
public class Person{
  String firstname;
  String lastname;

  public Person(String fname, String lname){

  }
  public String toString(){

  }
}
```

And this subclass, Student:

```
public class Student extends Person{
  Student(){
    super();
  }
  int studentID;
  int level;

  public Student(String fName, String lName, int gLevel){

  }
  public int getLevel(){

  }
  public String toString(){

  }
}
```

When I compile in DrJava, I get the error:

```
cannot find symbol 
symbol  : constructor Person() 
location: class Person
```

I'm not sure what the problem is. It's my understanding that the use of the super() constructor should resolve this problem, and that it's not even necessary in the code. My code matches any example I've seen online demonstrating inheritance in Java, but I'm continuing to get this error.

Comment: What do you think `super()` calls?

Comment: It's my understanding that super() passes the parameters in the parent class to the child class.

Comment: The other way around: from child to parent. But still, where does it deliver this? You don't have a constructor that takes no arguments.

Answer (score 5):

Calling `super();` supposes there's a default constructor in the `Person` class, while there isn't such, since you have a non-default one.

You have to *either* provide explicitly the default constructor:

```
public Person() { }
```

*or* pass two parameters in the `super` statement:

```
super("Firstname", "Lastname");
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because there is `no zero argument constructor` or `default constructor` present in your Person Class.

Since Every child constructor calls Parent Class Constructor in it's 1 line with `super()` implicitly So same way Student Class's Constructor Called and it was unable to find out default Constructor in Parent Class.

Why `Java Compiler` doesn't provide default constructor automatically/implicitly Since `parameterised Constuctor` is already present in your Parent Class